# Understanding Solving Simple Equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble explaining/understanding how the theorem

(1) $\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb R(x=y\iff x+z=y+z)$

applies to solving simple equations. Suppose we are working with the equation $p_1(x): x+1=0$ and we wish to determine the values of $x$ for which $p_1(x)$ is true. Rather than carrying out the usual "add $-1$ to both sides..." I want to understand why (1) says that $p_1(x)$ is equivalent to $p_2(x): x=-1.$

Comment: Um... the theorem says "add -1 to both sides".  That *is* what the theorem says.

Answer (score 1):

The theorems says:

$x +1 = 0 \iff x + 1 + z = 0 + z$ for all $z$.

In particular $x+1 = 0 \iff x+1 + (-1) = 0 + (-1)$

So $x+1 = 0 \iff x = -1$.

The theorem says if you ever come across $x + a = c$ you can solve it by adding $-a$ to both sides because $x + a = c \iff x + a +(-a) = c +(-a)$.

Comment: Haha, look I know I'm being dense. But something is just not clicking. My understanding is as follows: The theorem says that no matter what values we choose for x,y, z, the statement x=y $\iff$ x+z=y+z is true, which means that the two component statements, x=y and x+z=y+z have the same truth value for all x,y,z. So when we encounter the equation x+1=0 we know that the equation (x+1)+(-1)=0+(-1) has the same truth value for all x? We are treating (x+1) as a single real? Is that Ok?

Comment: Modus ponens:  1)  $(x + 1 = 0) \iff (x+1) +(-1) = 0 + (-1)$  2) $x + 1 = 0$ Therefore:  $(x + 1) + (-1) = 0 +(-1)$.  Or.  1) $x + 1 = 0$ and $x+ 1 + (-1) = 0 + (-1)$ have the same truth value.  2) $x + 1 = 0$ is true.  Therefore:  $x+1 + (-1) = 0+(-1)$ is true.  Is it the $x+1 + (1) = 0 +(-1) \iff x = -1$ that is throwing you off? that is simply: if $a = b$ and $a=c$ then $b=c$. so.....

Comment: 1) $x+1 = 0 \iff x+1 + (-1) =0+(-1)$.  2) $x + 1 +(-1) = x$ 3)$0 + (-1) = -1$. 4) $x + 1 = 0$.  So: 1 and 2 give us A)$x+1 = 0 \iff x = 0+(-1)$.  A and 2 give us B) $x+1 = 0 \iff x=-1$.  and B and 4 give us, via modus ponens C) $x = -1$.

Comment: We know that $x + 1 + (-1) = x$.  That has *NOTHING* to do with this theorem.  That has to do with definition of additive inverse and additive identity  And we know that $0 +(-1) = -1$  That has nothing to do with the theorem either.  That has to do with additive identity.  And we know that if $a=b; b=c$ then $a=c$.  That has nothing to do with the theorem, that is equality.  So we know $x+1+(-1) = 0+(-1) \iff x = -1$ but that has *nothing* to do with the theorem.  So ..... to be continued....

Comment: So we have 1) $x + 1+(-1) = 0+ (-1) \iff x = -1$ from basic math.  We have $x + 1 = 0 \iff x + 1+(-1) = 0+ (-1)$ and that *is* from the theorem.  We can combine them by basic logic $x+1 = 0 \iff x= -1$.   And *FINALLY* we were given as a basic premise and told that it is an indisputable fact that GOD on high has told us:  $x + 1 = 0$.  Therefore: $x = -1$.

Answer (score -1):

Well, let's use your example. Say we got the formula $p_1(x) : x + 1 = 0$. We state $x = y$, Just like you said. Since we got $x + 1$ on the left hand side, it must be that $z=1$. Now given your definition of $x$, $y$ and $z$, $x = y$ and $x+z=y+z$ are interchangeable. That means that if we get rid of $z$ on both sides, it states $x=y$. $$x + z = 0$$
$$y + z = 0$$
$$y = -z$$
$$x = y = -z$$
Since $z=1$ $x=y=-1$.
Just as clarification, there is no real use in using the way we just did. We better could've said $x=0-1=-1$ at the beginning. One of the explanations of this is that, not only is the formula clearly just another way of writing this, it also only has 1 unknown (or 2 of $z$ is unknown too). So I hope I made clear what the theorem does, but basically it's still the same.